# How should I handle sending event-based emails from a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, email, triggers

What's the best way to manage triggers for sending lots of different event-based emails from a Rails app?

For example, consider the following events that happen throughout the lifecycle of a user:

- User signs up
- User's comment gets viewed by someone else
- An item on a User's watchlist gets changed
- Remind the User to log in after 1 month of inactivity
- etc.

Comment: Whatever you do, *don't* send it from a database trigger.

Comment: What's the way to go, then? Cron job? Observers?

Comment: A trigger that inserts data into a queue table for later processing by an external tool (periodic by cron, or alerted via listen/notify) is fine. The key thing is not to try to actually send mail from a pl/perl trigger or whatever. It'll work but it's a terrible idea, and will do horrible things to performance.